# Lucene Search Multifield field query

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to search a string *hello brother* (wildcards is used) on multiple fields in java.

```
QueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, analyzer);
parser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);

parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR);
```

But my results are not showing in the expected manner. I want reults if any filed contain the string "hello brother", but it is showing results even for "hello" from one field and "brother" from another field. How can i solve this?

Comment: you can use QueryParser.OR_OPERATOR and test it !

Comment: Its not working with OR_OPERATOR either.

Comment: first , if you want to use wildcard query ,then you field must don't analyzed, second set AND operation and build query *hello brother* , if you do this ,then i think result is will show your expected manner ! you can try it .

Comment: U mean i should avoid using analyzer? When i tried to remove analyzer it is shwoing an error.How to remove analyzer?

Comment: u only need use KeyWordAnalyzer and it don't analyzer text!

Comment: tried that too...still showing same results

Comment: You want a phrase query?